# Reset counter for function repeats

Tags: jquery

I have a function that checks if certain element has an attribute and if it is not found the function runs again. It does it until the attribute is found or the maximum number of times this functions is allowed to call itself is reached.

```
var cnt = 0;

function myFunction() {
    if (!$('.myEm').is('[style]') && cnt < 10) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                myFunction();
                cnt++;
        }, 3000);
    }
}

myFunction();
```

However, if user selects an option in another element (myDropDown) the counter for the original function needs to be reset to zero and myDropDown needs to start running again.

```
$(document).on('change', '#myDropDown', function() {
    var cnt = 0;
    myFunction();
});
```

I'm struggling to reset this counter value. I put together a **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v9a5kpow/)** to show what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the reference to the timer in a variable, then call `clearTimeout()` on change of the `select` element. You also should remove the `var` statement before you reset `cnt` back to `0`, otherwise you will change its scope. Try this:

```
$(document).on('change', '#myDropDown', function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    cnt = 0;
    myFunction();
});
```

[**Update fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v9a5kpow/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The loop will keep running so you shouldn't need to call that again, just use the jQuery change function:

```
$('#myDropDown').change(function () {
    cnt = 0;
});
```

edit: just realized that the timer stops at 10, so updated the JSFiddle to restart the timer loop if it has reached 10.

See updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/91on7c1f/

Answer (score 0):

you are defining the cnt as local inside the change handleR you need to use the global variable. just remove var inside change handler